# Check multiple string values as OR Expression to be used with NgClass

Tags: angular

I am trying to use an expression where it will check for any of the given values inside the expression. I have managed to do this with:

```
<h2 class="heading" [ngClass]='{"redBackground" : info?.title == "Relationships" || info?.title == "In The Anime" ||  info?.title == "Anime" || info?.title == "Appearance" ||  info?.title == "Relationships" || info?.title == "In The Anime"}'>{{ info.title }}</h2>
```

Looking for a cleaner approach

Comment: You could put the logic into a property or method and return true if any of the target strings are matched are matched. Another approach would be to put all the strings in an array literal and use `["Relationships", etc].indexOf(title) !== -1` but I can't remember if the syntax is supported in that position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is notably shorter:

```
<h2 class="heading" [ngClass]='{"redBackground" : ["Relationships", "In The Anime", "Anime", "Appearance", "Relationships", "In The Anime"].indexOf(info?.title) >= 0}'>{{ info.title }}</h2>
```

or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes (not supported in IE)

```
<h2 class="heading" [ngClass]='{"redBackground" : ["Relationships", "In The Anime", "Anime", "Appearance", "Relationships", "In The Anime"].includes(info?.title)}'>{{ info.title }}</h2>
```

I would suggest to move it to TS code instead of have too much code in the template.